# Link in Edit mode, plain text in regular mode

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to have a hyperlink in the edit options of a grid column? The grid displays plain text when it is bound. But when it is in edit/add mode, this text needs to be converted into a hyperlink (which opens a popup). I couldn't find an option to have a hyperlink in the editoptions. I was able to do it as a button but I need a link. Is there a way of doing this? I have the following code -

```
colModel: [
           { name: 'Person', index: 'PersonName', width: 70, editable: true, edittype: 'button',
                                editoptions: {
                                    value: 'Select',
                                    dataEvents: [{
                                        type: 'click',
                                        fn: function (elem) {
                                            var left = (screen.width / 2) - (700 / 2);
                                            var top = (screen.height / 2) - (550 / 2);

                                            var popup = window.open("popup.htm", "popup", "resizable=1,copyhistory=0,menubar=0,width=700,height=550,left='+left+',top='+top");
                                            popup.focus();
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should check out the `custom` edittype, in which you need to define your own functions  `custom_element` and `custom_value` to build your form element.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#edittype